Attribute list error in FIRFirestoreSettings with Firebase Firestore SDK on Xcode 15.3
I've run into a build error after updating to Xcode version 15.3 in my project that incorporates the Firebase Firestore SDK.

An attribute list cannot appear here

The error points to a line in the FIRFirestoreSettings file. Specifically, it's this declaration:
ABSL_CONST_INIT extern "C" const int64_t kFIRFirestoreCacheSizeUnlimited = Settings::CacheSizeUnlimited;

Editing the SDK's files isn't an option since they appear to be locked or read-only. This error is persistent even in older project versions, suggesting it might be a compatibility issue with the updated Xcode.
I'm in search of a solution or workaround to this problem that doesn't entail direct modification of the Firestore SDK.
If anyone has encountered this issue or knows a fix, your insights would be greatly appreciated.

Update to Firebase 10.x.
That code was updated in 2022 - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/commit/5e832e5d400b9069855c8813828da62d8b7270b8

A workaround, if you have Firebase 9.x, is removing "ABSL_CONST_INIT " in that line of code.
Modify that line to:
extern "C" const int64_t kFIRFirestoreCacheSizeUnlimited = Settings::CacheSizeUnlimited;

Save the file and build again
